# Koin Moduledefinition on KoinTest

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, kotlin, koin

I try to use on a unit test (Kointest) my **ModuleDefinition** object (not Koin Module) but KoinTest only let me use the Object "**Module**".
If a try this:

```
startKoin {
    modules(uiModule)
}
```

The error message:

```
"None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied: 
public final fun modules(modules: List<Module>): KoinApplication defined in org.koin.core.KoinApplication
public final fun modules(modules: Module): KoinApplication defined in org.koin.core.KoinApplication"
```

Exists any way to use the ModuleDefinition object on Koin Test?

Comment: Can you show your uiModule?

Comment: What's a `ModuleDefinition` object? Please add it to your question.

Comment: I been working with a previous version of Koin. Right now on 2.0.1 is solved.